# How to select attribute or fallback value if attribute does not exist?

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to count the occurrences of every value for a specific attribute (e.g. @root) of every element that matches a query. Some of these matching elements do not have the attribute, but I want to count those as well (i.e. also list the amount of matched elements that did not have the attribute)

Currently I use this, but this does not match the nodes that dont have a `root` attribute. The counting is done by the application, which allows me to show intermediate results.

```
    //node[@rel='su']/@root
```

I want something like

```
    //node[@rel='su']/string(if .[@root] then @root else 'fallback-value')
```

The queries are run against Berkeley DB XML so XPath2 and XQuery might also be used to solve this.

edit: To clarify, I am looking for a query which treats the non-existence of the @root attribute as a special case; i.e. as if the attribute did exist and had 'fallback-value' as value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
//node[@rel='su']/(@root/string(), 'no-value')[1]
```

---

*Follows the original answer to the misunderstood question*

Why don't you just use

```
//node[@rel='su']
```

then? It will match both `node` elements that have a `@root` attribute and those who do not.

Given that a `node` can have at most one `@root` attributes, counting the nodes is enough.

Comment: It is for an application that shows all found values of @root and how often each of them occurred, which is why I need to query the value.

Comment: But how does this take care of `"count the occurrences of every value"`, as explicitly was asked for?

Comment: Given the initial code snippet I suppose that they will have code that operates on the nodeset returned by the query.

Comment: Sorry, indeed, we have. We just iterate over the results as they are found and count them as we go along. gioele's answer is a drop-in replacement for the original query and does exactly as I had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done using XQuery. First, collect the matching values while enforcing your fallback policy:

```
   let $matches := //node[@rel='su']/(data(@root), '')[1]
```

The above is a slighty corrected reformulation of the expression shown in your question. Note however that it will treat root attributes with a zero-length value the same as a non existing root attribute.

Then group by distinct value, and count the number of occurrences for each group:

```
   for $value in distinct-values($matches)
   let $count := count($matches[. = $value])
   return <value count="{$count}">{$value}</value>
```

When applied to this input,

```
  <x>
    <node rel="su" root="A"/>
    <node rel="su" root="A"/>
    <node rel="su" root="B"/>
    <node rel="su" root=""/>
    <node rel="su"/>
    <node rel="su"/>
  </x>
```

the result could be

```
  <value count="2">A</value>
  <value count="1">B</value>
  <value count="3"/>
```

For enforcing a specific order of the result, add an `order by` clause:

```
  for $value in distinct-values($matches)
  let $count := count($matches[. = $value])
  order by $value
  return <value count="{$count}">{$value}</value>
```

Comment: I really like this solution. Currently the counting is done in the application itself and this allows me to show intermediate results to the user, which is a feature I really like to maintain. If that was not necessary, this would have been the best solution for the overall problem.

Answer (score 0):

What about this ?

```
//node[@rel='su' and not(@root)]
```

This should match the nodes without the `root` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
concat('Having @root: ', count(//node[@rel='su']/@root ),
       ', Not having @root: ', count(//node[@rel='su'][not(@root)]),
       ', Having @root occur ',
       floor(count(//node[@rel='su']/@root ) div count(//node[@rel='su']) * 100),
       '% of the time.'
       )
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select=
  "concat('Having @root: ', count(//node[@rel='su']/@root ),
          ', Not having @root: ', count(//node[@rel='su'][not(@root)]),
          ', Having @root occur ',
          floor(count(//node[@rel='su']/@root ) div count(//node[@rel='su']) * 100),
          '% of the time.'
         )
  "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<t>
 <node rel="su" root="2"/>
 <node rel="su" root="1"/>
 <node rel="su" />
 <node rel="su" root="4"/>
 <node rel="su" root="5"/>
 <node rel="su"  />
 <node rel="su" root="7"/>
 <node rel="su" root="8"/>
 <node rel="su" />
 <node rel="su" />
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
Having @root: 6, Not having @root: 4, Having @root occur 60% of the time.
```

Comment: I was not looking for statistics on the @root attribute itself, but on the values it is found with. I want to treat non-existence of the attribute as a special value, so I can count how often it occurs in the same way I count all found values.

Comment: @Jelmervdl: If so, you must accept Gunther's answer. Also, you need to improve significantly your question defining and not to leave people guessing and wasting their time.